# Does the MathJax formatting function in Linux computers?

Tags: support, mathjax

I have a linux computer, openSUSE 13.1, and am trying to ask a question in the math stackexchange.

However, as I am typing the paragraph underneath the text box where I am typing does not produce any markups.

Do Linux users have to install any software to ensure the markups function? Or can we just not see markups as we type them?

Comment: Do you have Javascript enabled in your browser? What is your browser, by the way?

Comment: im running chromium browser.  i didn't know i had to enable javascript; a search that led to the java FAQ page stated that linux user's should be using firefox for times when java is needed.  is this known to be true here?

Comment: You don't need Java, you need JavaScript.  Which is enabled by default in most browsers, including Chromium. When you visit [this site](http://www.mathjax.org/), do you see formulas on the right? Do you see this integral? $$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$$

Comment: ok, i restarted my machine and now the formatting is marked up in Latex. go figure.

Comment: I have an old machine, hand-me-down Linux; I have put in a convenient power strip, most nights i log off and then shut down the power to the machine. It really seems to help, not just with web browser stuff.

Comment: I agree with @WillJagy: logging off Math.SE  helps with many things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is: yes, it does. The list of browser/OS combinations supported by MathJax is [here](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/misc/browser-compatibility.html).